# How to hide a linux pc from network?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, virtual-machine

I installed a Linux virtual machine in my windows machine, but I don't want my network admin see the Linux VM. Is there any way to hide it?

Comment: How is he seeing it so far?

Comment: Don't mess with your network admin, they don't appreciate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That depends on how you allow your VM to access the network.

If you allow the VM to access the network through [NAT](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_nat) it should be pretty hard to spot as it doesn't get an IP-address. (It sort of hides behind the host's network.)

Note that a competent network admin can probably find it anyway if he went out of his way to find it.

Comment: Note that `p0f`, the **Passive OS Fingerprinter** can identify hosts based on purely on-the-wire data.

Answer (score 1):

firewall the machine, reject icmp packets so it wont ping, and only allow inbound connections which are related and established to outbound ones. This should be good enough, more or less.

maybe also setup port knocking if you want to get in from outside.